# Accessing an array of objects stored in a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to access an array of objects, with javascript, that is stored in a json file on my site. I could just include the array of objects in my js, but I'm trying to learn how to use json files.

I would like to store the array as a variable in my js file. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is better to post with an example of your current code.

Comment: Here is a great post on this subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery?rq=1.

Comment: I suggest to read http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ .

Answer (score -1):

You just need to pass the String to:

```
JSON.parse("{my:'object'}")
```

To read the file from the server, just use the [ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$.get( "my-endpoint/test.json", function( data ) {
  var jsObject = JSON.parse(data)
});
```

I guess Jquery might already have parsed the `data` and you do not even need to call `JSON.parse()` - try it out :)